# CA2000 Microsoft Reliability

Tags: code-analysis

```
       Warning CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'ProtocolHelper<TClass, TClassType>.ProcessApplicanceData(object)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object '<>g__initLocal5' before all references to it are out of scope.
```

Below is the code and above is the warning I got.

```
 public WCFServiceClient(Callback callback, WDaaSAuthMode authMode)
    : base()
{
    AuthMode = authMode;
    CallbackInstance = callback;
}
public T Client
{
    get
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>(CallbackInstance, EndPoint);

                return CreateClient();

        }
        return _client;
    }
}
public Callback CallbackInstance { get; set; }
```

}

I got this above warning in many cases like that. I tried "using" and "try, finally" but nothing solved my problem. Could anyone help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the relevant code. It probably wants you to use `using`.

Comment: @leppie : I have added the relevant code. Pls help me. I don't have much time as I have to complete this by today itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls suggest me on this..

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that generated code is not analyzed? that variable name sounds like a compiler generated one.

[image]